# Help with quiz questions

Tags: discussion

I'm working through the Kanzen Master N3 series. I want to know if I can ask for help with some of the quiz questions.

The format of these questions is usually something like

|Some Japanese| ( ) |Some Japanese|

a. Answer 1    b. Answer 2    c. Answer 3

You then need to choose a, b or c to occupy the place at the round brackets.

Is asking for help with these questions frowned upon? If not, what should I title these questions so that other people have an easy time finding them?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I would think that questions regarding what types of questions are allowed would be appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's fine to ask these questions, also to give the original multiple choice format. But **the question itself should stand on its own**.

I would suggest that you make clear what part you understand, and what you need to know to answer the question.

For example, if there are four choices two of which you can eliminate (say, for grammatical considerations), there is no reason to ask about the "differences" of all four.